# How to sort date column in Datatables framework?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a date column sortable by date but it only sorts by the day.

URL to my example:
https://aetos-us1.infinitybht.app/store/81113d0060/?ui=dashboard
( click on "Requests", then sort the "Creation Date" column.)

The js code I'm using:

$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'ddd.mm.YYYY HH:mm' );

```
$('#requests_table').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "datetime-moment", targets: 6 }
        ],
)}
```

Thanks for helping me in this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

Ref : http://jsfiddle.net/mlotfi/6gzpnjgx/

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs : [
        { type: 'time-date-sort', 
          targets: [6],
        }
    ],
    order: [[ 6, "desc" ]]
});
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but I need to order date in a specific format, so I need to have the control on what format is going to be ordered. in your example its 2015-03-09T14:46:54.678-04:00. the js framework I'm using has this article but I couldn't get it working: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18